# Timer onReceive not working inside NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following timer:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timeRemaining = 10
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                if(self.timeRemaining > 0) {
                    Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                            if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                                self.timeRemaining -= 1
                            }
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Time is up!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `NavigationView` view, the timer updates and works, but like that it doesn't, what's going on here and how can I update it while in the `NavigationView`? Or is there a better practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to attach observers to non-conditional views, like

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                if(self.timeRemaining > 0) {
                    Text("\(timeRemaining)")
                } else {
                    Text("Time is up!")
                }
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in        // << to VStack
                if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                    self.timeRemaining -= 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:** some thoughts added (of course SwiftUI internals are known only for Apple).

.onReceive must be attached to persistently present view in NavigationView, the reason is most probably in conditional ViewBuilder and internal of NavigationView wrapper around UIKit UINavigationControler.

> if you remove the condition and have a single Text view with onReceive inside the VStack inside the NavigationView, nothing is ever received

If after condition removed it is attached to `Text("\(timeRemaining)")` then all works (tested with Xcode 11.4), because there is state dependency in body.

If it is attached to constant Text then there is nothing changed in body, ie. dependent on changed state - `timeRemaining`, so SwiftUI rendering engine interprets body as static.

Comment: Why is this the case? I am suffering from the same problem as the OP and this is a valid solution but it would be helpful to understand why. It would also be helpful to understand the impact `NavigationView` has on this. Remove the conditional and use `onReceive` on a single `Text` view and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have encountered the same thing and could not figure it out the reason. What I found was that timer is not publishing any values. Because It gets cancelled once. I have connected second subscriber to the timer and it does not get any value or completion. However when I call .onReceive on outer space of NavigationView, both its closure and the second subscriber started getting values. But still I do not know why the timer is cancelled when I put `.onReceive` inside the NavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

İ had same problem but not one-to-one. I Solved like this : my ContentView has .onApper {binancemanager.fetch()} —-> i call here but i moved it to
@main
struct MyApp:{WindowsGroup.Vstack.Content.